# Render layout to display notch in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, display-cutouts

I've tried adding layoutInDisplayCutoutMode shortEdges but it had no impact. I needed to stretch a layout to the top, something similar to the images shown in Netflix android app

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your theme

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```